# Melting/casting my data into shape

Tags: r, reshape

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

And I need it to look like this, where net=gross-tare:

[image]

How do I do this?

---

I started by melting the data, then casting as columns, and then creating new columns for the net readings.

```
  df_m <- melt(df, id = 1:3)
  df_c <- cast(df_m, ... ~ variable + type)

  df_c$wr_net  <- df_c$wr_gross  - df_c$wr_tare
  df_c$wc_net  <- df_c$wc_gross  - df_c$wc_tare
  df_c$tsa_net <- df_c$tsa_gross - df_c$tsa_tare
```

Which gives

[image]

But now I can't figure out how to melt this table to get the dataframe to look the way I need with a column for 'type' with values 'gross' and 'tare' and 'net'.

Is there an easier way? Am I barking up the wrong tree with melt/cast?

---

You can reproduce a small sample of my data using this...

```
  df <- structure(list(train = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AC0485n", class = "factor"), 
    position = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), type = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("gross", "tare"), class = "factor"), 
    wids_raw = c(24.85, 146.2, 26.16, 135, 24.7, 135.1), wids_corr = c(26.15, 
    145.43, 27.44, 134.43, 26, 134.52), tsa = c(24.1, 139.2, 
    25, 133.6, 24, 131.1)), .Names = c("train", "position", "type", 
    "wr", "wc", "tsa"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need is to use ddply:

```
ddply(df,.(position),.fun=function(x){
newrow <- x[1,]
newrow$type <- "net"
newrow[4:6] <- x[x$type=="gross",4:6] - x[x$type=="tare",4:6]
return(rbind(x,newrow))
})
```

which returns,

```
   train   position  type     wr     wc   tsa
 1 AC0485n        1  tare  24.85  26.15  24.1
 2 AC0485n        1 gross 146.20 145.43 139.2
 3 AC0485n        1   net 121.35 119.28 115.1
 4 AC0485n        2  tare  26.16  27.44  25.0
 5 AC0485n        2 gross 135.00 134.43 133.6
 6 AC0485n        2   net 108.84 106.99 108.6
 7 AC0485n        3  tare  24.70  26.00  24.0
 8 AC0485n        3 gross 135.10 134.52 131.1
 9 AC0485n        3   net 110.40 108.52 107.1
```

EDIT:
And I think this works if you really want to use melt/cast:

```
dd <-  melt.data.frame(df_c,id.vars=1:2)
dd$type <- factor(do.call("rbind",strsplit(as.character(dd$variable),"_"))[,2])
dd$variable <- factor(do.call("rbind",strsplit(as.character(dd$variable),"_"))[,1])
```

Comment: Hey whut-do-ya-know! I like it. Though I'm still curious how to finish it using `cast` and `melt`. Can anyone provide comment on that?

Comment: I just tried it with my actual dataframe (there are 16 columns, of which wr, wc, tsa are the last three. I've changed the code to `newrow[,14:16] <- x[x$type=="gross",14:16] - x$type=="tare",14:16]` but it's giving an error `Error in Ops.data.frame(x[x$type == "gross", 14:16], x[x$type == "tare", :- only defined for equally-sized data frames`. 14:16 is correct since df[,14:16] shows the wr, wc, tsa columns.

Comment: Sorry, I think I had a small typo in my code that may cause it to not work in every circumstance. I fixed it above. Try changing newrow[,14:16] to newrow[14:16]. I added a potential solution using melt/cast.

Comment: Thanks, your melt/cast works! Unfortunately ddply with [14:16] still gives the same error about `equally-sized data frames`. Any idea what gives?

Comment: I just did a summary of my data, and there are 67694 type = "gross" and 67919 type = "tare". Could that be the reason? I guess I'll have to remove some type = "tare" values.

Comment: Sometimes melt() is weird, if you want to force it use `melt(df, c())`

Comment: @Tommy O'Dell: Sorry you're still having problems. Hard to help much more w/out having your full df to work with. One possibility is NAs, which my function won't handle gracefully, since NA=="tare" will evaluate to NA.

Comment: One issue might be that your full data probably has multiple trains. In that case, the call should look like: `ddply(df,.(train, position),function(x)...`, so that each chunk is just the few appropriate rows. Note that this may take a while with that many columns, especially if any of your columns are factors. (The combine step in ddply can be very slow when reconstructing factors...)

Comment: FYI guys, it worked when I removed all `train-positions` not having both a row for `tare` and a row for `gross`. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4):

If you really wanted to do it just using reshape, here's how I'd do it:

```
library(reshape2)

df_m <- melt(df, id = 1:3)

df_c <- dcast(df_m, ... ~  type)
df_c$net <- df_c$gross  - df_c$tare

df_m2 <- melt(df_c, 1:3)
names(df_m2)[4] <- "type"

dcast(df_m2, ... ~ variable)
```

Comment: There's a reshape2? Awesome! Just going through the documentation now.